# Computer Management / Microsoft Management Console (MMC): why do these look different?

Tags: mmc

Right clicking on Computer and selecting Manage (asks for the administrator password and then)
brings up the Computer Management console. From the Task Manager I can see that the name of
the executable which is used to open this graphical user interface program is mmc.exe.
However, if I type mmc.exe from the DOS command prompt to open the application it does
not ask me for the administrator password and what I see looks different (there are a
few more entries in the menubar, but the left-hand column displays an empty root folder
and nothing more. Since I am new to MMC, I'd like to ask these questions:

1. In order to run the program in the same way as right-clicking Computer and selecting Manage,
   what command line flags should I supply to mmc.exe on the command line?
2. Why do these two instances of MMC look different?

Thanks.

Comment: First match when googling "Windows MMC": [Step-by-Step Guide to the Microsoft Management Console](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742442.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MMCs are wonderful little sets of management tools that support snapins. Knowing which one does what can be a challenge.

Some MMCs are customized and you can save a configuration.

Another option is to use Microsofts built in MSCs, such as the one you are using.

When you right click "Computer" and click manage you are actually running `compmgmt.msc`.

Try launching compmgmt.msc from the command or run line and you will see the window you are looking for.